# Reactive Form reset and forms validation

Tags: angular, forms, angular-reactive-forms

I know this question is asked many times before. i want to reset my form and validation after submit. i used formGroup to create a form. i used a button for submit the form if the form is valid i reset the form by using form.reset() it clear the fields but not the error i also try to use

```
this.form.markAsPristine();
this.form.markAsUntouched();
this.form.updateValueAndValidity();
```

to reset the form validation but it didint work

from the code given below i can reset the form but the input fields remain dirty or touched as a result input field marked as red. can someone suggest me what is best practice of creating a form, reset the form and validation.

my html code is

```
    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="outline" style="width: 100%;">   
        <input type="text" matInput formControlName="title" placeholder="Enter Module Title" #message maxlength="50">
        
        <mat-error *ngIf="form.controls.title.hasError('required') && (form.controls.title.dirty || form.controls.title.touched)">
          Module Title is <strong>required</strong>
        </mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>

  <button (click)="save()"> Save</button>
```

this is my .TS file

@ViewChild('my2Form', { static: false })
my2Form!: NgForm;

```
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      title: ['',[Validators.required]],
    });

   save()
     { if(this.form.invalid)
      { this.form.markAllAsTouched();
         return;
       }
     else
      {
      this.my2Form.resetForm();
      this.form.markAsPristine();
      this.form.markAsUntouched();
      this.form.updateValueAndValidity();
      this.form.markAsPristine();
        }
```

[image]

Comment: disable save button until formGroup is invalid instead of `markAllasTouched`

Comment: i want to show the user that he/she misses these fields so i cant disable the button

Comment: I sthis what you need? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-eu5eas?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: please use angular material matinput and 2-3 fields you will get the error i.e after reset input field marked as red

Comment: If you create stackblitz for your problem, it will be easy for me to help you

Comment: in this if you click on save button the form value reset but the color of input field remains red  https://angular-mat-form-field-m8evpn.stackblitz.io/

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zfgvvl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html @navnath

Comment: You want to show error when user touch or dirty the filed and also the the time when he submit form?

Comment: yes but if the user submit the form i just want to reset the form along with the validations  the stackblitz i shared i reset the form values successfully but the input field in html color remains red . i want that if the user submit the form the form get clear and the input field color back to its original form

Comment: Finally got it . checck it out https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ljxhyl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In template just add `type=button` :

```
<button type="button" (click)="save()">Save</button>
```

In component.ts

```
if (this.form1.invalid) {
    this.form1.markAllAsTouched();
} else {
    this.form1.reset();
}
```

[Angular demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ljxhyl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: what if i am using ngSubmit or button type submit ?

Comment: The in template `#form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="save(form)"` and in save do `save(form: NgForm)` and in body to reset `form.resetForm();`

Comment: remove commented code here to check https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ljxhyl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Thank you sir for the help it sove my problem but  can you please check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zfgvvl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: user type="button" because you are calling (click)="save" so type submit is notuseful ..https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n174o5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts